# JDBC API DataBaseMetadata.getTables fail with Oracle 18c

Tags: java, jdbc, upgrade, oracle18c

After upgrading the database from Oracle 11g to 18c, the following line goes in infinite hang when trying to fetch the database tables.

```
databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", {"TABLE"});
```

Driver: ojdbc8.jar 18.3.0.0

Server: Oracle18c

Answer (score 0):

We tested this with 18.3 JDBC driver and did not find any issues.